# Creating diagonally moving button winforms C#. Help needed

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I am a beginner and the syntax is unknown for me. Please provide me the code. Thanks in advance.

```
button1.Location = new Point ( button1.Location.X ++, button1.Location.Y ++,);
```

This what I did but it gives an error that argument is missing.

Comment: No,this is not how StackOverflow works. You should show some effort to do it by yourself and just come here if you got problems. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This site is not meant to do your homework or projects for you, please show us what you want to accomplish and what you have tried. If you have a specific problem we will be willing to help you.

Comment: button1.Location = new Point ( button1.Location.X ++, button1.Location.Y ++,); This is I tried but it gives an error that argument is missing.

Comment: Hi @Stephenjunior you need to show some more code, and use the code formatting - I'll [edit] your question to give you a hand. The error is most likely not on this line of code `argument is missing` - you can double click the item in the error list and the IDE (Visual Studio) will take you the line which has that error.

Comment: Candidly I can not move forward at all. I know for prof this is simple but for beginner that knows nothing should be support. The puzzle is described above. Thanks for support

Comment: See my answer mate and *do* pick up a book and try to learn more. Also when you are debugging and troubleshooting you have to go after the problem like a dog after a bone. After a few years you will instinctively just know how to solve stuff. Also, google is your friend, use it like **C# "argument is missing"** and trawl through all the results, verifying which apply and trying them. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the extra comma:

```
button1.Location = new Point ( button1.Location.X ++, button1.Location.Y ++,);
```

Should be:

```
button1.Location = new Point ( button1.Location.X ++, button1.Location.Y ++); //no comma after .Y++
```

> Tip - Whenever you are calling a method or in this case instantiating a class use the tooltip to see the methods signature and pass it what variable types it expects. In this case a Point class does not accept 3 arguments, only 2. Visual Studio is complaining there is no 3rd argument in the parameter specified.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this but anymore this is not solution. Actually my written code is 0 I need some real solution for my puzzle.

Comment: So did you remove that 2nd comma, then do a Build/Compile/F5 and the compile error still persists?

Comment: Here is a good explanation, which reflects my diagnosis of your problem: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384077.aspx dont forget to Tick answers as correct, it will each you a few rep points and let everyone know your problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks. But I need new code lets forget about my code and start  from 0.